# phpMyAdmin Installation on a Windows PC

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

How can I install phpMyAdmin on my PC? I have already PHP, MySQL and IIS installed.

How can I install it in Windows 10? And if I do upgrade to Windows 11, should i do the same?

Comment: I want to use IIS (Microsoft Internet Information Services) as a local server, the latest version of PHP and the latest version of MySQL.

Comment: This link should help you: [https://theitbros.com/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-iis-in-windows-8server-2012](https://theitbros.com/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-iis-in-windows-8server-2012).

Comment: I'd start at https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install and post back here if you have any specific problems with the process.

Answer (score 0):

f you are trying to get a test/preprod environment, you should take a look at **Xampp**. It provides a database server, Apache web server, php and phpmyadmin and is very scalable and configurable.

Xampp : https://www.apachefriends.org/fr/index.html

And of course, Xampp can be used on Windows 10 as well on Windows 11.